# SonarQube 6.2 - configure wizard option not there on dashboard?

Tags: sonarqube, dashboard

I have setup SonarQube 6.0 on our server and shown specific column on project dashboard using Configure Wizard(1st Image). Now I have migrated our SonarQube version to 6.2 I don't see configure wizard option (2nd Image)  to add specific column to track what are the unresolved issue, bugs, vunnerabilities etc.

Do you have any idea of customizing dashboard with columns for SonarQube 6.2.
[image: SonarQube 6.2]
[image: SonarQube 6.0]

Answer (score 2):

"Dashboards" per se were dropped in SonarQube 6.2. They were replaced with standard landing pages. Your first screenshot is of the Projects page, which is not configurable.

Comment: You mean to say you can not have projects details shown in Screenshot 2?

Comment: Screenshot 2, with "Configure Widgets" highlighted, is of a dashboard. Dashboards went away. The ability to see project metrics should return soon via the projects space - the logged-in landing page.

Comment: Shouldn't you have the feature moved BEFORE removing the functionality? I know this is not the LTS version, but couldn't you have left the dashboard customization until you had the ability in the Projects space?